# Lambda function returns null with google-distance-matrix (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I need to calculate the distance using the [google-distance-matrix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-distance-matrix) API in a NodeJS Lambda function but It just returns null when I run the function.

```
var distance = require('google-distance-matrix');
distance.key('xxxxxxxx');

var origins = ['San Francisco CA'];
var destinations = ['New York NY', '41.8337329,-87.7321554'];

var dist = function() {
    distance.matrix(origins, destinations, function (err, distances) {
        if (!err) {
            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: distances
            }
        }
    });
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return dist()
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use callbacks correctly and you did not return the value from the `distance.matrix` callback into the `dist` function.

What you would have to do is:

```js
var distance = require('google-distance-matrix');
distance.key('xxxxxxxx');

var origins = ['San Francisco CA'];
var destinations = ['New York NY', '41.8337329,-87.7321554'];

var dist = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      distance.matrix(origins, destinations, function (err, distances) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve({
          statusCode: 200,
          body: distances
        });
      }
    });
  });
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return await dist();
};
```

Comment: I had to remove one curly bracket but thanks it works now